Translation notes for different versions of the Bible?
I was looking at the Greek of 1 John 3:12 - and I noticed how different versions translate the passage differently. Some say that Cain murdered his brother, while others state that he killed / slew his brother. While the Greek permits all of these - choosing to call Cain a “murderer” instead of a “killer” or “man slaughterer” has implications for how we interpret Gen 4.
Personally I would argue that Cain was judged like a man slaughterer and not as a murderer (which the Law demands death for); see Numbers 35.
The translators are thus pushing an interpretation of Gen 4 on us as if as though the author of James was giving us this interpretation. While it maybe justified, I currently don’t see how.
Examples of versions that say Cain murdered his brother include the NASB and the NIV. On the other hand, the KJV says that Cain slew his brother.
To help me settle the matter, I would like to know why the translator’s of the NASB and NIV (among others) gave us the translation they did. Is there a good resource or set of resources that can give us insight into translation decisions that were made for select passages by various versions of scripture?
EDIT:
For some additional context, I asked whether Cain was to be considered a murderer on the Judaism SE, and got some interesting replies worth checking out: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/146425/35595

The law was not given yet when Cain killed Able

Note that there has been semantic drift in the terms.  In the time of the KJV, "murder" meant what we would call "assassinate"; "kill" meant "murder"; and "slay" meant "kill."

@Kristopher They ate of the fruit of knowledge - which represents the Law - and knew good and evil. At any rate, it was God who judged Cain - not a human judge. So there’s no issue with interpreting the passage in light of the Law if we assume that God is consistent in his judgement. Rather, it would be more problematic to argue that God was using a different standard to judge Cain - showing him mercy despite never owning up to or repenting of his actions.

That's where you got it wrong pal, Cain murdered his own brother. He physically assaulted him, the blood of your brother is crying to me in the fields

@SoFewAgainstSoMany the idea of blood defiling the land applies equally to manslaughter and to murder. See Numbers 35:32-33

Cain could not be judged as there was no witness and no confession. He chose to leave Adam's household (the presence of the Lord) rather than resolve the matter.

@NigelJ,  if there was no judge then how comes the Lord was a witness?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany He will witness at the Day of Judgment, after all are raised to be judged. Until then, Courts on earth must suffice. And in Cain's case, one must prove motive, premeditation, intent, non-self-defence, circumstance, cause of death etc etc etc.

@NigelJ, There was no human government in the stated period to suggest the possibility of a "court" trial. Governments start to manifest with the enslavement of Israelites in Egypt. Cain will be judged because Jesus said from the blood of innocent Abel. Though he received partial judgment to punish him for that action.

It is true that the word being questioned in 1 John 3:12 has been variously rendered, 'murdered', 'slew', 'slaughtered', 'killed'. It is also true that differentiation is  made in the Old Testament between murder and sanctioned warfare, where the carnage of killing enemies deliberately is not put alongside premeditated murder. There is a matter of legality here.
Of course, there was no 'war' going on between Cain and his brother Abel. There was no sanctioning of any action resulting from the jealous brother. Indeed, God warned Cain (knowing the hatred in his heart), giving Cain time to turn away from the outcome of harbouring such hatred.
By today's Western standards Cain might be judged to be a man-slaughterer, instead of a murderer, for the 'only' witness to the crime was God. Yet predetermined actions took place; not spur-of-the-moment loss of control, nor due to antagonism on the victim's part. Cain chose the location and the time, with no witnesses present to see him carry out what he planned to do. Yet 'murder' is a judicial term to be applied after a legal judgment about a case has been made. Is that why it would be wrong for any translation to pronounce 'murder' when there were no witnesses, and God never said 'murder'?
The NIV (and other translations) say in 1 John 3:12 that Cain murdered his younger brother. However, the Greek word is σφάζω sphazo, which only occurs here and in Revelation 5:6, 9, 12; 6:4, 9; 13:3, 8 & 18:24. This word means 'kill, slay, wound'. The word sphage means 'slaughter'.
The NIV Bible Commentary (1986 edition) explains in its Study Notes why it said 'murder'. The relevant part of the explanation states:

"In Cain is seen the horrifying nature of hatred: he murdered, and
that his brother. And why did he murder him? ...The apostle has no
time for moral sluggishness which refuses to see ultimate principles;
and brushing aside all possible secondary and contributory causes he
declares that the sin was Cain's. Cain could not bear the contrast of
his brother's righteous actions with his own actions which were evil,
and the first murder became a monument to self-love." NIV Bible
Commentary, p. 1580, article by R.W. Orr (1986 ed)

This certainly has implications for what Genesis 4 states. But, 'interpretation'? Here is the NIV Commentary again, on saying 'murder':

"As was said on 3:7, the first effects of sin were seen in the family,
and it is entirely consistent with this that the first murder is
fratricide... No suggestion of previous tension between the brothers
is mentioned... We should not import any redemptive meaning into the
brothers' sacrifices, cf. 8:20; they were the recognition of Yahweh's
lordship. Both gave of what they had... The reason for the rejection
is suggested in vs. 6, 'If you do what is right'. The probability is
that he resented having to accept God's lordship (cf. v.13).
The Hebrew of v.7 is difficult, but we need not doubt that the general
sense has been given by NIV when it sees sin personified as a ravenous
beast. Speiser's rendering, 'sin is a demon at the door', is worth
mentioning.
8. Cain said to Abel 'Let's go out to the field': i.e. the open country. The addition to the Hebrew text is necessitated by Hebrew
linguistic usage, and is in all the versions. It suggests that the
murder of Abel was premeditated... Abel's blood was crying to God for
vengeance (v.10) and therefore it was not the responsibility of others
to take vengeance." (Ibid. pp.118-9)

This is why the NIV gives 'murder' both in Genesis 4 and 1 John 3. And the Apostle John, writing his first epistle, did not need to 'interpret' anything with regard to stating what the crime of Abel was. He did not have 21st century ideas about such matters, as the rest of his surrounding verses show. Indeed, John quoted the words of Jesus, heard with his own ears,
"Anyone who hates his brother is a murderer" [Matthew 5:21-22], and you know that no murderer has eternal life in him. [Galatians 5:20-21 & Revelation 21:8] 1 John 3:15 NIV

+1 for providing a reasonable argument as for why one might think Cain was a murderer and for the NIV commentary. However, I think details are being read into the biblical account that aren’t there. For instance: it doesn’t say that Cain invited Abel out anywhere. It just says they happened to be in the fields. Abel raised animals like sheep - it wouldn’t have been odd for him to be in the field. Or at least that is how most translations render it - I do see that the NIV specifically adds the bit about inviting him out to the field…. That is interesting

I found why some versions say that Cain invited him out to the field: this is due to a difference in the manuscripts. The Masoretic Text (the official one used in Rabbinic Judaism) does NOT say that. However, it is present in what sounds like all the other manuscript families (the Greek for instance). So potentially something that was added to the Septuagint that got carried on

First, in English,

"murder" is any illegal killing
"slaughter" usually means the butchering of animals for food, or, (when applied to a human) the violent killing of a person.

Thus, when applied to a person, the difference in meaning is very slight to almost insignificant.
Now, the meaning of the Greek verb, σφάζω (sphazo) means (BDAG) "slaughter".  In the NT it only occurs in 1 John 3:12, and Rev 5:6, 9, 12, 6:4, 6:4, 9, 13:3, 8, 18:24 - a total of 10 times.  It consistently means to put to death by violence.
Such an act 9when done to a human) is obviously "murder" in modern English.  Thus, the word could be legitimately rendered, kill, slay, mortally wound, kill by violence, slaughter, etc.
That Cain's act of killing his brother was definitely an illegal "murder" is evidenced by the fact that he was strongly reprimanded by God for the act and severely punished as recorded in Gen 4.

As with philosophical works, within theology terms can take on different and more refined meanings. Murder is one such concept within scripture that is well defined. As per Numbers 35, within the context of scripture murder is not any form of illegal killing - but specifically an illegal killing that was committed intentionally / with malice. On the other hand, an unintentional manslaughterer / killer is not deemed to be a murderer. Any time "murder" is used within scripture it must be consistent with the legal usage found in the Mosaic Law.

Also, if we go checkout https://www.dictionary.com/browse/manslaughter, it gives the primary definition of manslaughter as "Law. the unlawful killing of a human being without malice aforethought" - which is consistent with Numbers 35 and how it should be understood within scripture.

Finally, if you compare Cain's punishment to what is found in Numbers 35 you will see that his punishment was consistent with a crime of manslaughter and NOT with murder. The punishment for murder was death; end of story. A manslaughterer, on the other hand, was to be exiled (like Cain) to a city of Refuge. As long as the manslaughterer remains in his designated place of exile, he is protected by Law from being put to death for his crime - just as Cain was given a mark to protect him from others trying to kill him.

@RyanPierceWilliams - that is all very well but the Sinai law and jurisprudence did not exist in Cain's time and so that reference is irrelevant.

God was the one who passed judgment on Cain. Assuming God is consistent and true in passing judgment, then we should expect to see even prior to the Law being given by Moses that God carries out justice in a manner consistent with the Law. It would be far more problematic and contradictory to argue that Cain was judged by altogether different standards from what is found in the rest of scripture. In fact, just a few chapters later we get the Noahide Covenant which likewise demands that a killer be put to death

@RyanPierceWilliams - really?  Then why did not God provide the cities of refuge as per Num 35?  None existed for another 2500 years!!  And why did not God provide a priesthood and temple?

Furthermore, Genesis was written looking ahead to Exodus and the rest of the Pentateuch, and not in isolation. Hence God is referred to as YHWY even though tentatively God gave his name to Moses in Exodus 3 and at no point before that. Indeed, the whole of Genesis - both in narrative and metaphorically - anticipates the rest of the Pentateuch. Israel itself is presented as a kind of second Eden even. As such, it does not make sense to attempt to interpret Genesis in isolation from what the author of Genesis knew was going to happen.

@RyanPierceWilliams - that does NOT explain why Cain was guilty!  You may believe what you will.  I take the Bible as it is without fancy theories.

first, the temple was built by Solomon - which occurs after the events in the Pentateuch. However, God did provide temples: our own bodies. At any rate, the presence or absence of a temple is irrelevant to justice. And the cities of Refuge were a safe place that manslaughterers could go and live out there days without fear of being put to death. Cain got the same: he was exiled from the Lord’s presence and given a mark to prevent others from killing him. The same principles are being applied in both cases.

scripture doesn’t say whether Cain was a murderer or not - beyond a questionable translation that is. You have to study the Law to know which is the case.

manslaughter can also be considered to doing something that will indirectly result in the death of another person, an example is a doctor ignoring a patient, he knows if he doesn't attend to the patient then the patient will die.

Yes God is consistent, and a God of justice. But he's also a God of mercy. The whole point of the gospel is that God's justice and mercy in harmony is not fully revealed except in Jesus. It's worth meditating on Paul: God presented Christ as a sacrifice of atonement, through the shedding of his blood—to be received by faith. He did this to demonstrate his righteousness, because in his forbearance he had left the sins committed beforehand unpunished... (Romans 3.25)

@RyanPierceWilliams, 1John 3:14: "he who is not loving the brother doth remain in the death" — Genesis 4:9: "And Jehovah saith unto Cain, 'Where is Abel thy brother?' and Cain saith, 'I have not known; my brother's keeper -- I [i.e. Are you sure, God, in what you ask me, Cain]?'" — John 13:16: "verily, verily, I say to you, a servant is not greater than his lord," — John 13:34: "A new commandment I give to you, that ye love one another"

Abel should have sensed that his brother was acting weird, for the first time his brother is asking him to accompany him to the fields, why didn't he do so yesterday or the day before? Abel heard that voice but ignored it because that voice from our instinctive conscious is always expressed in weakness, this idea must have been pushed aside by other thoughts such as He is going to teach me some cool farming techniques, and then to his surprise Cain shows him his true intention.
Cain murdered his own brother because you can see how he plots to lure him  to the fields where Adam and Eve are not watching, then he slows down a little to let Abel lead the way, then he pulls out the jawbone of an ass and hits him at the back of the head.
Murder is always direct, manslaughter is always indirect, the perfect example of manslaughter is the case of a doctor who knows ignoring a certain patient will lead to his death and he does it anyways, the doctor has not touched the patient but his action of ignoring him results in the death of that patient unlike the case of a doctor who injects a lethal substance into a patient. The earlier is indirect, the later is direct.
The versions that create the meaning of murder are the correct ones.

It is worth noting that not all translations say that Cain invited Abel out into the fields. I’m not sure why the difference in translation for Genesis 4:8, but it does seem to add weight to the argument that Cain’s attack was premeditated IF it is correct that he invited him out into the field.

@RyanPierceWilliams, it is the most logical conclusion, Abel was going on about his daily business of shepherding and then Cain draws him with a made up excuse and then this leads to that up to the climax of the sin. Abel is the first saint born of men, from the blood of innocent Abel....

If Abel was a shepherd then it would have been normal for him to be in the field; he wouldn't have needed inviting. And you are overlooking the Cain's judgement and how it mirros that for a manslaughterer rather than that of a murderer; I think that really needs to be addressed before one can rightly conclude that Cain was a murderer.

@RyanPierceWilliams, indeed it is true that Abel was a tenderer of sheep and Cain a farmer.

I found that the Masoretic Text does not contain the bit about Cain inviting Abel out to the field, but it is present in other manuscript families - like the Greek. So perhaps something that got added into the Septuagint and carried on.

@RyanPierceWilliams, he had to draw him out of the presence of other human beings so he could carry out his evil desire for he knew that it sinful.

If you think he was guilty of murder, then why did God not judge him as a murderer?

@RyanPierceWilliams, because Jesus said Cain will be judged. He said from the blood of innocent Abel...  Google that verse and you will have your answer. Cain will be required to give account on judgment day.

So are you saying that if he was a manslaughterer but not a murderer he would not face judgement for his sins?
